# Editing classified image raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, editing, erdas-imagine

I have an unsupervised classification dataset of a SPOT 6 image created in ERDAS IMAGINE and I now want to edit the class names in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

I have done this successfully for a number of unsupervised classification datasets already, however the one I am currently working on will not allow me to edit.

When I click Start editing, I just get the following error:

[image]

The file is an unsigned integer 8-bit raster TIFF file created in ERDAS IMAGINE.

Comment: You can add field to the table and populate it using field calculator

Comment: @FelixIP The 'add field' option is disabled for the raster

Comment: Result of classification is single band integer raster. Yours is something different. Can you see the table?

Comment: @FelixIP As far as I can see from the attribute table it is a single-band 8-bit unsigned integer raster. Yes, I can see the table - it has all the 40 separate classes plus empty classes going up to 255(which the other classified files did not have). However, I tried exporting it in ArcMap to create a new file and now I cannot see the attribute table at all and it will not let me build one.

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.